# Trying to print JSON data using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have a Discord BOT using python and I am trying to get print the JSON information using the Enjin API. I can get it to print everything if I do `print(Data)`, but as soon as I try displaying a *certain* bit of information, such as the `variables_values`, it doesn't display and gives me the following error:

> Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I have a previous function; called `Status` that uses a different API, and I **can** get it to work with that, but I just cannot get the following code to display the values in `variables_values` bracket. (As you can tell, I am not great with JSON | Also, ignore the **xxxxx**)

```
async def GetVariable(message):
    R = requests.get('http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/api/m-shopping-purchases/m/47325895/user_id/19363576')
    Data = R.json()

    await client.say(Data["varaible_values"])
```

Here is what I want displayed, when I run the ?GetVariable command: 
`jacobdallred` - which is in the `"variables_values":{"Steam64ID":"jacobdallred"}` place.

Instead, it gives me the error previously mentioned.

Here is what it displays if I only `client.say(Data)`: (Uploading to Hastebin to display nicer)
https://hastebin.com/huwubiwawe.json

Comment: Your results `R.json` is an json array, not json object

Comment: Tip #1: Avoid using variable names like 'data', 'var', 'str' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the first element of that `json` response array. Like this:

```
await client.say(Data[0]["items"][0]["variables_values"]["Steam64ID"])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for giving an answer so quick, however I am getting the following error: `Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'variables_values'`